# Pinch zoom and setFrame causes drawing issues in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, frame, pinch

I have a UIWebView, and I load a local file into it.

1. When the document is loaded
2. I make a pinch gesture
3. and after that I set a bigger width for the UIWebView.

**Result:**
This causes that a black bold stripe appears on the right side of the UIWebView.

Do you know how this issue can be solved?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Here are some sample code:

```
@interface ViewController () {
    __weak IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
    CGRect initialFrame;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    initialFrame = webView.frame;
    webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"chapter7" ofType:@"ppt"]]]];
}

static int c = 1;
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    c++;
    if (c % 2 == 0)
    {
        //full screen
        CGRect frame = initialFrame;
        frame.origin.x -= 100;
        frame.size.width += 100;
        [webView setFrame:frame];
    }
    else
    {
        //initial
        [webView setFrame:initialFrame];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView has to reload when it's frame size is changed in order for it to render in the increased space as well.